# IntelliJ-IDEA's Python type checker - incorrect expected type?

Tags: python, intellij-idea

In the following code:

```
from typing import List
def test() -> List[str]:
    ret = ["Hi", "Hi"]
    return ret
```

I'm receiving the following warning on the function definition line:

```
Expected type 'Integral", got 'str' instead
```

I can't see any reason why IntelliJ-IDEA's python module would interpret this simple function as returning an list of Integral rather than str. Is this a type checker bug?

Comment: I think the error is from `List[str]` itself, rather than the function's return - what *is* `typing.List`?

Comment: It's part of mypy, which allows type checking on Python; however, if you use python's standard list (lowercase), as in def test() -> list[str] you get the exact same error with the str.

Comment: When you say "error", do you mean a Python error, or a warning from PyCharm? Presumably the latter, as `list[str]` just wouldn't work at all. Note that e.g. *"PyCharm 4.5 EAP builds have **preliminary support** for PEP 484, since this PEP isn't finalized yet"* (https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html), so you shouldn't be too surprised if it isn't yet fully working.

Comment: It was a warning; I just updated my question, thanks for clarifying that with me. I wasn't actually aware that this was experimental, so I'll just disable it for the time being, barring any other suggestions.

Comment: This should have been solved with more recent versions of PyCharm, which support a deeper/smarter analysis and understanding of these types.

Answer (score 1):

Pycharm only have some preliminary support for type hints.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `typing.List` is a simple wrapper class that **extends** builtin `list` class. It helps in type hinting and doesn't allow creation of `new` list using itself.

Here is the current code for `typing.List`:

```
class List(list, MutableSequence[T], extra=list):

    __slots__ = ()

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwds):
        if _geqv(cls, List):
            raise TypeError("Type List cannot be instantiated; "
                            "use list() instead")
        return _generic_new(list, cls, *args, **kwds)
```

By doing `typing.List[str]`, you are trying to call the method `__getitem__` on an object `typing.List` (which is a type). Also note that

This translates to following:

```
typing.List.__getitem__(str)
# or
list.__getitem__(str)
```

Now if you see, what does list indexing method expect, it expects an integer like `a[0], a[1]`. In this case instead of an `int` like `0, 1`, it received a ***type*** `str`

Hope this gives you a more holistic view of `typing.List`.